# ASP.NET Core, How Does Runtime Reason About Startup Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, interface, app-startup

In Startup.cs I have a `Startup` class which exposes `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()`. The `Startup` class is used in the `Main()` code path as such...

```
webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Many questions:

- How/why are `Startup` callback methods inferred if `Startup` does not
  implement an interface?
- Is the runtime using Reflection?
- Why isn't the generic type an interface?
- What if `Startup` class does not implement `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()`?

Comment: Read about fundamentals in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

Even though the ASP.NET Core uses reflection in order to call `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods, you can implement the `IStartup` interface.

It is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartup?view=aspnetcore-3.1) under the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting** namespace.

The main purpose why it exists is that it supports integration testing. For further details, please check this [excellent article](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/06/resolving-asp-net-core-startup-class-from-the-di-container/).